# Make some text of the calendar module multilingual?

Tags: views, i18n-l10n, datetime

I instaled and got running fine the 'calendar' module. I just need to make some texts multilingual.

This module generate a view which shows a monthly calendar, then you can change to weekly canlendar, day calendar and so on.

To switch between this display this module show some links above the calendar. The text for these link are what I need to make multinlingual (see picture 1)

These links are taken from the name of the display of the view (see picture 2)

How can I accomplish this.
Thanks
[image: picture 1]
[image: picture 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calender links are defined in the calendar/theme/theme.inc in the function `function template_preprocess_calendar_main(&$vars)` here you can see that the `$calendar_links`  use the function `date_t()` as found in the date_api.module and can be translated. In other words, if i am correct, you can translate this through the translate interface, as found on admin/build/translate.

Comment: makes sense, I'll try to translate it.